# SQL Server (Azure) split comma-separated string into multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database

I have the following data in Azure SQL Server (*Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Sep 20 2018 21:40:02 Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation*)

```
ID    Name
1     US_Android_100x200_blue
2     UK_iOS_100x200_green
```

I want to split them into a table like this:

```
ID  Country  Device   Size     Color
1   US       Android  100x200  blue
2   UK       iOS      100x200  green
```

What are the ways to do it? I looked it up and it shows to use STRING_SPLIT but I haven't been able to find a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`STRING_SPLIT` splits a string into a *set* consisting of a single column, not into multiple columns in the same row.

If there are always 4 components, you can use this long thing:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ID int,    Name sysname)
INSERT @x VALUES
(1,'     US_Android_100x200_blue'),
(2,'     UK_iOS_100x200_green');

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT x.ID, y.value, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY x.ID ORDER BY CHARINDEX('_' + value + '_', '_' + x.name + '_')) 
  FROM @x AS x CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(x.name, '_') AS y
)
SELECT ID, Country = [1], Device = [2], [Size] = [3], Color = [4]
FROM x PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS p
ORDER BY ID;
```

Or you can hack it:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Name = REPLACE(Name, '_', '.') FROM @x
)
SELECT ID, 
  Country = PARSENAME(Name, 4),
  Device  = PARSENAME(Name, 3),
  Size    = PARSENAME(Name, 2),
  Color   = PARSENAME(Name, 1)
FROM x
ORDER BY ID;
```